# Android Studio & Firebase: CardView Loading Problem

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a screen that shows my movie names and their pictures which are in my Firebase with `CardView`. Functionally, it works perfectly. But the problem is; firstly it shows the `loadingPanel`, secondly it shows [the movie names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCMLP.jpg), lastly it shows [them with the pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMWYt.jpg). Normally, it should show the `loadingPanel` until all names and pictures are shown.

My database's structure is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSpFy.jpg). `name` is the string which is the name of my movie. `profilePic` is the string that contains the picture link from Firebase storage.

Where is my fault? Can you fix it?

**Movies.java**

```
package com.example.XXXX;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Movies extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference reference;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Profile> list;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    private String message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_films);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Films");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list  = new ArrayList<Profile>();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Profile p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Profile.class);
                    list.add(p);
                }
                adapter = new MyAdapter(Movies.this,list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(Movies.this,"Ooops... Something is wrong.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");

        ImageButton backButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton13);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Movies.this, Menu.class);
                i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE",message);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Movies.this, Menu.class);
        i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE",message);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.XXXX;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Profile> profiles;

    public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Profile> p){
        context = c;
        profiles = p;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cardview,viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        myViewHolder.name.setText(profiles.get(i).getName());
        Picasso.get().load(profiles.get(i).getProfilePic()).into(myViewHolder.profilePic);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return profiles.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView name;
        ImageView profilePic;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.film_name);
            profilePic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.filmProfile);
        }
    }
}
```

**Profile.java**

```
package com.example.XXXX;

public class Profile {
    private String name;
    private String profilePic;

    public Profile() {
    }

    public Profile(String name, String profilePic) {
        this.name = name;
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getProfilePic() {
        return profilePic;
    }

    public void setProfilePic(String profilePic) {
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
    }

}
```

Comment: So can you please be more specific about what in your code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: We show the loadingPanel because app is fetching all names and photos, and when it ends, all names and pictures should be ready. But in now, when loadingPanel is gone, only names are shown. After 1-2 secs (depends your internet rate) the pictures are shown

Comment: And how would you like to behave?

Comment: loadingPanel should be shown until all names and pictures are settled and ready.

Comment: I understand, I'll write you an answer right away.

Comment: so much thanks, if you want any information more, please inform me

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, I understand that you want to display a `ProgessBar` "until all names and pictures are settled and ready".

When you are using the following line of code in your `onDataChange()` method:

```
findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It means that you hide the `ProgessBar` when you finished getting the data from the database. What you have done till now, you only got the name and a **reference** (link) to the actual picture, **not** the picture itself. Since you already have the name, this is instantly displayed in your `TextView`, that's why you see it first. To display the actual image, it takes some time to download it and idsplay it in your `ImageView` using `Picasso`. Depending on your connection speed and the state, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before the image is downloaded and displayed, that's why you see it delayed. This time depdends on the size of the image. To solve this, you have two options.

The first one would be to store a thumbnail of your actual image that has a small size and can be displayed almost instantly or you can attach a listener to each picture and display the entire view, only when the image is downloaded. I'm not familiar with `Picasso` but when using [Glide for Android](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), you use RequestListener's [onResourceReady()](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/8a9b63cfd9462f6c4bb40f655d3bd25cc02d7d0d/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestListener.java#L82) method.